# Stick ImageView to Another ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-imageview

So I'm trying to have a `ImageView` stick to the corner of a second `ImageView` which rotates, and I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I've tried to get the coordinates of the corner of the rotating `ImageView` and setting that to the location of the other `ImageView` and it doesn't work. Is there any way that I could make this work? 
Thanks

CODE

**rotate.xml** file used to rotate the main `ImageView` (the thing I want the second `ImageView` to stick to)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
/>
```

**activity_main.xml** (image is the `ImageView` that is rotating and I want character to stick to one of the corners of rotating)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/darkGrey"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="400px"
        android:layout_height="500px"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/image"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50px"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:layout_above="@+id/image"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/image"
        android:id="@+id/character"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: By "stick to", do you mean move around with it?

Comment: I imagine that you need to wrap both the `ImageView`s in a `RelativeLayout` and rotate that instead.

Comment: @KamranAhmed Yeah, thats what I'm trying to do